# How to calculate the a Probability with Z-Score.

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

I have a $ \mu = -1  $ and $ \theta = 6 $. I am supposed to find the probability $P(5 < X < 11)$.

My Attempt:

$$P(5< X < 11) $$
$$P(\frac{5--1}{6} < \frac{X--1}{6} < \frac{11--1}{6}) $$
$$ P(1 < Z < 2) $$

Now what? How do I calculate the Z-score without a table? Do I just integrate the normal probability density function (I tried that... I'm not sure if I am doing it wrong or what)?

btw, the answer the professor gave was:

$$P(1 < Z < 2) = .1359 $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a CDF $F_X$, $P(a< X \leq b)=F(b)-F(a)$. You'll need a table or a calculator or something. [Trying to integrate the PDF of the standard normal distribution will only bring you sadness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Cumulative_distribution).

Comment: Welp, that explains a lot. I don't have a scientific or graphing calculator, or the textbook with the tables (can't afford them), so no wonder I'm having trouble with normal distributions and z-scores. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Chase: You can find tables freely available on the internet. You can even find calculators that lets you calculate the CDF of any normal distribution at specific points.

Comment: @Chase although, I would recommend sticking with tables if you are using tables in your class. You want to get really efficient at using tables for exam purposes. Tables are, of course, freely available online.

Comment: For one table, [see this.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_normal_table)

Comment: @crf Funny thing, I don't think she ever mentioned a table in class exams. I think she expects us to use a calculator. I don't have one, so I'm guessing that if I can show all the correct work (basically everything right up until a calculation) and show what's going on I will do fine. Well, I hope.

Comment: Also, if anyone is still here, how does one do the same for any other type of distribution? Just integrate? What if say, for Binomial distributions, I have n =64, p =.2 and x = 1.16?

Comment: @Chase This is a separate question and maybe you should pose it separately, but the answer that I gave you is general: if you have a CDF then you have everything. If the distribution is *continuous* with PDF $f_X$ then the CDF is $F_X(x)=\int_{-\infty}^xf_X(t)dt$. The binomial distribution is not continuous, so that won't help you in this case, although the idea is the same. For a discrete distribution with probability *mass* function $p_X$, $F_X(x)=\sum_{y\leq x}p_X(y)$. Sometimes (in the binomial case for instance), this can be tough to put into a nice closed form.